# Express validator is not working with post value?

Tags: javascript, express, express-validator, req

This my current code, it is working fine,
But I need to access req.body.type in createValidationFor, if I try to access code req.body validation stops working I don't know why

```
   router.post(
        '/login',
        createValidationFor('email'),
        checkValidationResult,
        (req, res, next) => {
            res.json({ allGood: true });
        } );

function createValidationFor(type) {

    switch (type) {
        case 'email':
            return [
                check('email').isEmail().withMessage('must be an email')
            ];

        case 'password':
            return [
                check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
            ];
        default:
            return [];
    } }

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(422).json({ errors: result.array() }); }
```

Modified code :-  I am trying access req inside the createValidationFor function but validation stops working after that

```
router.post(
    '/login',
    createValidationFor,
    checkValidationResult,
    (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({ allGood: true });
    }
);

function createValidationFor(req, res) {
    var type = req.body.type;
    switch (type) {
        case 'email':
            return [
                check('email').isEmail().withMessage('must be an email')
            ];

        case 'password':
            return [
                check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
            ];
        default:
            return [];
    }
}

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(422).json({ errors: result.array() });
}
```

Comment: I assume what you want is to first check for e-mail and then check if the password matches like how we do Microsoft or Google logins? In that case, I recommend that you separate your endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Your function `createValidationFor` should not receive `req, res, next` parameters because it is not a middleware, it just inserts (returns) the appropriate validation chain according to `type` value as the only needed parameter (in your example `type = 'email'`). Only function `checkValidationResult` is responsible for all the middleware stuff: sending error if validation errors exist or pass control with `next()`.

```
function createValidationFor (type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'email':
            return [
                check('email').isEmail().withMessage('must be an email')
            ];
        case 'password':
            return [
                check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
            ];
        default: 
            return [];
    };
};

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    };
    res.status(422).json({ errors: result.array() });
};

router.post(
    '/login',
    createValidationFor('email'),
    checkValidationResult,
    (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({ allGood: true });
    }
);
```